# Checking the type of a variable

Tags: javascript

What's the best way to find out whether a variable is a string or not (and, likewise, a number, a boolean, etc.)?

Usually you will find:

```
function isString(value) {
    return typeof value === 'string';
}
```

But people forget that one can also create string objects directly using `var foo = new String("bar");` - whether that is a good idea or not is an entirely different matter.

So what's the way to go here? I can think of - and have seen - various approaches (somewhat simplified):

```
// option 1
function isString(value) {
    return (typeof value === 'string') ||
           /^function String\(\)/.test(value.constructor + '');
}
```

or

```
// option 2
function isString(value) {
    return (typeof value === 'string') ||
           (value.constructor === String);
}
```

or

```
// option 3
function isString(value) {
    return (typeof value === 'string') ||
           value instanceof String;
}
```

Is there a "best" way to go about this? Or are they all equivalent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Among the three existing options, the first feels rather hacky to me because it uses a regular expression to test the string representation of `value.constructor`. It works, but it still feels hacky (maybe it's just me).

The second option would only work for string literals, strings created from concatenating existing objects and objects made with the `new String()` constructor, whereas the third option should work with objects made with the `new String()` constructor or any other object that inherits from `String()` *(I'm not sure about JavaScript inheritance; can someone confirm this?)*.

The `constructor` property exists also for primitives/literals, not just wrapper objects created using `new`. This makes the `typeof` check in the second option quite redundant:

```
function isString(value) {
    return value.constructor === String;
}

alert(isString("test1"));             // true
alert(isString(new String("test2"))); // true
```

However, unlike the third option it may not work with objects with constructors other than `String()` that inherit from `String()`.

My answer uses strings as an example to reflect the question but the same idea applies to `Number`, `Boolean`, `Function`, `Object`, `Array` and other types.

Comment: Neat, I didn't know that (at least I never thought of it ;) Doesn't really answer the question, though.

Comment: @n3rd: How does it not answer the question other than it not being one of the three existing options?

Comment: +1. Was just about to post this. Does this catch (gasp) subclasses of String though?

Comment: @Skurmedel: Probably not. I've never been able to wrap my head around JavaScript inheritance.

Comment: @BoltClock: the question was whether or not all three methods are equivalent in both semantics and performance.

Comment: @n3rd: I see, I didn't catch that you were asking specifically about the existing options. I'll edit my answer to clarify.